# os-prober can't find Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2, dual-boot

I have two hard drives, one with Ubuntu 22 (Jammy) and a separate drive with Windows 10. System boots to Ubuntu by default, as set in BIOS. I'm trying to get my grub boot menu to list the Windows 10 drive, as I previously had on Ubuntu 18.

1. The Windows drive is mounted (visible and accessible in `/media`)
2. `ntfs-3g` is installed

`sudo os-prober` still doesn't detect. Naturally, `grub` also fails (yes, I have `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false`)

Any ideas?

Boot-repair summary:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2bCVt7QPJY/

Comment: Are both installed in same boot mode, probably with newer system both should be UEFI. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair   &           
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Added pastebin summary. Please note that the 2 nvme drives are the relevant ones (others are just externals).

Comment: hmm can u tell me why you have windows in /media usually when you are dual booting grub only need to find efi for windows located in /boot/efi

Comment: When I was trying to solve the same problem, I frequently saw advice to disable _Fast Boot_ option in Windows

Comment: It's only in `/media` because I opened the drive in Thunar (file manager) to view the files and ensure it is accessible. Idk if it automatically mounts there.

Comment: You mixed boot modes. Windows is in old BIOS/MBR mode where Ubuntu is in UEFI boot mode. Since on separate drives you can dual boot but not from grub, only from UEFI boot menu. Once you start to boot in one mode, you cannot switch. Windows really should be in UEFI boot mode on gpt drive. Note conversion from MBR to gpt will totally erase drive. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI/gpt mode since 2012. Old BIOS mode was really  for older hardware.

Comment: Hey @oldfred, thanks for that info. I suspected it was something like that. I must have installed my prior Ubuntu 18 in MBR mode and not realized it. So my only option is to reinstall one of the OSes?

Comment: You can convert an Ubuntu install from UEFI to BIOS with just a reinstall of the correct grub. You may first need a bios_grub partition of 1MB unformatted if UEFI install of Ubuntu is gpt. I would keep ESP. Ubuntu uses grub-pc for BIOS boot and grub-efi-amd64.efi for UEFI boot. You have to boot live installer in correct mode to make repairs. Since UEFI system probably better to reinstall Windows, conversion rarely works from BIOS/MBR to UEFI/gpt as different partitions requried.